# Randomly picking pedestrians to figure out where to go in the city

Tags: probability

$2/5$ of couples are from out-of-town (oot), while $3/5$ of couples are from town. If a couple is from oot, the probability the husband and wife will give correct directions independently is $3/4$. If a couple is from town, the husband and wife always give correct directions independently of one another. Suppose you ask a random couple for directions, what is the probability that this direction is correct?

So we have a random couple $x$. The probability that they are from out of town is $2/5$, and the probability they will give me correct directions is $3/4$. So is our result just $(2/5)(3/4) = 6/20$?

Comment: Presumably both couple members have to give the same correct answer, so your $3/4$ should be $9/16$. And you forgot about the in town people.

Comment: Would that just be (2/5)(9/16)+(3/5) then?

Comment: That's my choice of answer. Depends what ask a couple means, and what correct means. If one oot partner gave the right answer and the other gave the wrong answer, I am counting that as wrong in calculating the $9/16$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When asking a couple 'out of town' we have 4 options :

```
Husband   Wife   Output 

Wrong     Wrong    X 

Wrong     Right    X (confused who I believe)

Right     Wrong    X (confused who I believe)

Right     Right   (Yes this is the direction)
```

So we need to calculate the probability of them giving a right direction `husband and wife will give correct directions independently is 3/4` 
So the probability is $(\frac{3}{4})(\frac{3}{4})=\frac{9}{16}$

you will get right directions by **either** asking a couple 'out of town' and get [$(\frac{2}{5})(\frac{9}{16})$] **OR** couple 'from town' and get [$(\frac{3}{5})(\frac{1}{1})$]

Total probability to get **Right** directions will be
$$(\frac{2}{5})(\frac{9}{16}) + \frac{3}{5}$$
$$\frac{9}{40}+\frac{24}{40}$$
$$\frac{33}{40}$$

P.S: The answer was edited after noticing the comment of Andres, Never read questions fast :p

**EDIT**: according to your comment

`If both gave the same answer`
let W=wrong and R=Right

$P(W)=\frac{1}{4}$, $P(R)=\frac{3}{4}$ for each one of them, so all possible cases would be:

`(W, W)`   $(\frac{1}{4})(\frac{1}{4})=\frac{1}{16}$

`(W, R)`   $(\frac{1}{4})(\frac{3}{4})=\frac{3}{16}$

`(R, W)`   $(\frac{3}{4})(\frac{1}{4})=\frac{3}{16}$

`(R, R)`   $(\frac{3}{4})(\frac{3}{4})=\frac{9}{16}$

So if both gave same answer it is **either** (W, W):$\frac{1}{16}$ **or** (R, R):$\frac{9}{16}$

Probability of them giving same answer is $(\frac{1}{16})+(\frac{9}{16})=\frac{10}{16}$, and probability of them giving different answers is $\frac{6}{16}$

So the probability of both gave right answer is $\frac{\frac{9}{16}}{\frac{10}{16}}=\frac{9}{10}$ ...

Comment: What if we ask: if the couple gave you the same direction, what is the probability they are correct?

Comment: $\frac{9}{10}$, i will confirm it after lunch break ;)

Comment: Can you so quickly? I don't have much time.

Comment: @Parker: edited, btw is it kind of homework or something?

Comment: No. This is a practice problem for my exam.

Comment: Why is the probability they both give the right answer $9/10$.

Comment: @Parker, see edit, (don't mind about my question I just wanted to know which level and in which country by curiosity)

Comment: No problem. So would the total answer be $\frac{2}{5}\cdot \frac{9}{10}+\frac{3}{5}$?

Comment: I would say this is the answer of the question (knowing that all the couple give the same direction, calculate the probability to get to the right place)